# Issue on toggling switch button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a custom switch system at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/63uGq/3/) with below code.

Both `#left` and `#right` are functioning perfectly but I have some issues on `#sw` which is supposed to toggle to left or right. If user selected  then click on this must shows left and switch button and so on

```
 <div class="switchbox">
    <div class="btn-group switch">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="left">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sw">Switch</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="right">Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
var scrollWidth = 49;
var scrollWidthsw = 49;
var pos = 0;
$("p").html(pos);
$("#left").on("click", function () {
    $(".switch").animate({
        left: '-=' + scrollWidth
    }, 300);
    pos = pos - scrollWidth;
    $("p").html(pos);
});
$("#right").on("click", function () {
    $(".switch").animate({
        left: '+=' + scrollWidth
    }, 300);
    pos = pos + scrollWidth;
    $("p").html(pos);

});

$("#sw").on("click", function () {

    if (pos == 0) {
        pos = pos + scrollWidth;
        $(".switch").animate({
            left: '-=' + scrollWidthsw
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $(".switch").animate({
            left: '+=' + scrollWidthsw
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63uGq/4/).

I have added an extra variable `toggle` to store the current toggling position. Is that ok?

Comment: Thanks Manun, I need 5 more minutes to accept the your solution as correct. but mean while can you please also let me know how to get the ID or value of the selected "Left" or "Right" button?

Comment: To get the Id in which function? I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean if user click on Left or right should't be hard to get the id of clicked btn but how about Toggle button? How to know which switch selected like Yes or No?

Comment: Actually `toggle` points to the buttons. If its value is 1 then the button is left and if it is 0 then button is right. You can find the button using the `toggle` variable. Got it?